# @EJB dependency injection cannot classcast Object to Object$view29

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, cdi

**I fixed it by moving the package of EJBs into the WEB module instead of the EJB module. Does anybody know why?**

I keep getting the following error. It says the EditEnterpriseSessionBean isn't the same class as EditEnterpriseSessionBean$$$view81.

The error consists of three parts:

> 21:18:36,880 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-40) UT005023: Exception handling request to /EntWeb/ListEnterprisesServlet: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: **Could not instantiate ListEnterprisesServlet** [..]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: **Failed to construct component instance** [..]
>
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: **Can not set EditEnterpriseSessionBean field ListEnterprisesServlet.edtEnterprise to EditEnterpriseSessionBean$$$view81**
>           at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167)
>           at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171)
>           at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) [...]

Do you have any ideas on this one?

Thanks in advance!

Full stack trace:

```
Context Path:/EntWeb
Servlet Path:/AddOrderServlet
Path Info:null
Query String:null
Stack Trace
javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: Could not instantiate AddOrderServlet
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:227)
io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.getServlet(ManagedServlet.java:169)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:72)
io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:282)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:80)
io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:172)
io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:199)
io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:774)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I fixed it by moving my EJB classes from my EJB module into my WEB module. Why does it work now, and not before!?

Comment: Were you deploying an ear?

Comment: @JohnAment Yeah I deployed an EAR, with EJB,Web & JPA as modules. I checked and the ejb.jar (and web.war) was in the .ear file.

Comment: Please provide your full stack trace.  If I had to guess, you're ending up with duplicate classes in your EAR, inspecting your output EAR would be the only way to confirm.  In general, EAR deployment is not particularly encouraged.

Comment: @JohnAment I appreciate your efforts! I added the stack trace to the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have separate ejb and war module, you should use remote interfaces. If you include the ejb module inside the war module, two ejb beans will be created. The ejb packaged in the ear and the other set from the jar file included in the war module.

At runtime, this is chaos, as two sets of beans with different classloaders are available for your war module

Comment: Since the EJB and Web modules are in the same EAR, I thought @ Local is supposed to work. Changing the @ Local to @ Remote works.
I guess this means that the ejb.jar is executed in a different VM than the web.war? Otherwise @ Local is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use the @Local interface make sure that the interface is only in the lib folder of the ear file and not in the lib inside the war file. If you are using Maven, you could set the dependency scope to provided for the pom file of the war project.